# Invalid parenthesis number and its position in a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am trying to find the number of invalid parentheses and its position. I have used an array to hold the invalid parenthesis position number. But myArray.pop() is not triggering.

```js
function processData(input) {
  var myArray = [];
  var paranthesisIndex = 0;

  for (C of input) {
    paranthesisIndex++

    if (C === '(') {
      myArray.push(paranthesisIndex);
    } else if (C === ')') {
      if (myArray.length < 0 && myArray[myArray.length - 1] === '(') {
        myArray.pop() //not working
      } else {
        myArray.push(paranthesisIndex)
      }
    }
  }

  console.log(myArray.length)

  for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(myArray[i])
  }
}

processData("())()");
```

output

```
5
1
2
3
4
5
```

expected output

```
1
3
```

Comment: `myArray.length < 0` how will this *ever* be true?

Comment: Also `myArray[myArray.length - 1]` will give you the *index* of the bracket as that's the only thing you keep in `myArray`, therefore `myArray[myArray.length - 1] === '('` will also never be `true`.

Comment: ...and even then all the indexes in `myArray` are wrong because you do `paranthesisIndex++` before you actually record the index. Thus you're always off by one. I would heavily suggest learning how to step through code with a debugger in order to understand how exactly it works, as currently you have a lot of basic errors that should have been caught easily by yourself if you had debugged your code.

Comment: By the way, what the output if `(()())()`?

Answer (score 0):

You used  `if( myArray.length<0 ...`  so your code never runs because the array should has no element in order to run `if` block. Maybe you wanted to use `if( myArray.length> 0 ...`.